# I have to prove the following Lemma: "A graph is k-colourable iff it is k-partite."

Tags: graph-theory

My proof goes as follows:

Suppose our graph G is k-partite. Then the vertices of G can be partitioned into k disjoint sets, say V1,...,Vk such that no two vertices within the same set are adjacent. Now, colour the vertices in V1 blue, in V2 red and repeat this up to the set Vk. So we need k-colours to colour all sets.

Now suppose G is k-colourable. Let V1 be the set of vertices that is red, V2 blue and colour all sets up to Vk with k different colours. Clearly, no edge joins a vertex in V1 to a vertex in V1 up to no edge joining a vertex in Vk to a vertex in Vk. Hence, G is k-partite.

I'm not sure if this proof is correct so any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: It's okay, but don't say "clearly". Say why: two vertices in V1 are the same color by definition, a properly-colored graph has no adjacent vertices of the same color, and if there were an edge they vertices would be adjacent.

Answer (score 1):

While your idea is correct, I think this exercise is too much of a tautology to not be really pedantic about it. Let‘s turn your proof into a formal argument.

First we recall the following definitions. A **graph** consists of a pair $(V,E)$ of a set of vertices and a set of edges. We will write $v\sim v‘$, if there is an edge joining the vertices $v,v‘\in V$. A graph is **$k$-partite**, if you can partition the set $V= V_1 \sqcup … \sqcup V_k$ into mutually disjoint subsets $V_i$ in such a way that for all $i$ and all $v,v‘\in V_i$ we have $v\not\sim v‘$. A graph has a **proper $k$-coloring**, if there exists a function $c:V\rightarrow \{1,…,k\}$ such that $c(v)=c(v‘)$ implies $v\not\sim v‘$.

A priori these are two different definitions. It is kinda obvious, that they encode the same information though. If you have a $k$-colored graph, you can partition its vertices by considering the subsets $V_i = c^{-1}(\{i\})$. Disjointness follows from the welldefinedness of the function $c$, the fact that $c$ is a proper coloring shows $k$-partiteness. Conversely, if you have a $k$-partite graph with partitions $V_i$, define the function $c:V\rightarrow \{1,…,k\}$ sending $v\in V_i$ to $i$. This function is welldefined, since the $V_i$ are disjoint, and it is a proper coloring, since the $V_i$ defined a $k$-partition.